# Nested ng-repeat - search not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use nested ng-repeat inside ng-repeat, because I have an array with the object, and child object. And my table need to have table inside table
Here is JSON

```
{  
   "1009":{  
      "id":1009,
      "serial_number":"1009-U",
      "campaigns":{  
         "52":{  
            "id":52,
            "name":"testSLOV"
         },
         "47":{  
            "id":47,
            "name":"IMA PODJELE"
         },
         "44":{  
            "id":44,
            "name":"TEST DUPLO"
         },
         "30":{  
            "id":30,
            "name":"ag3"
         },
         "26":{  
            "id":26,
            "name":"fdgdfsg"
         }
      }
   },
   "1051":{  
      "id":1051,
      "serial_number":"1051-U",
      "campaigns":{  
         "52":{  
            "id":52,
            "name":"testSLOV"
         },
         "43":{  
            "id":43,
            "name":"test weather"
         },
         "39":{  
            "id":39,
            "name":"default2"
         },
         "37":{  
            "id":37,
            "name":"ag5"
         }
      }
   },
   "1500":{  
      "id":1500,
      "serial_number":"1500-U",
      "campaigns":{  
         "51":{  
            "id":51,
            "name":"ag10"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I need to set parent ng-repet to , and child ng-repeat to 
here is example

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searcht">
       <tr>
          <td>{{item}}</td>
       <tr>
       <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="3" style="cursor: pointer;">
              <table style="width:100%;">
                 <tbody>
                     <tr ng-repeat="campaign in item.campaigns | filter:search">
                         <td width="250px"><a ui-sref="campaign({campaignId: {{campaign.id}}})">{{campaign.name}}</a></td>

                     </tr>
                 </tbody>
              </table>
          </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>

 </table>
 <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label >Search</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" 
         placeholder="Search">
    </div>
  </form>
```

When I try to use search filter to search in table I get error

> Error: [filter:notarray]

If I move finst ng-repeat to  filter working, but in this case I cant get on new  child ng-repeat to work

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
   <td>{{item}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="campaign in item.campaigns">
   <td>{{campaign .name}}</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Right after [filter:notarray] you should get link like [this](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.0/docs/error/filter/notarray) with explanation and examples how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your json structure. `ng-repeat` take `Array` instance but you have hash `Object` instance.

```
{"1009": {...}, "1051": {...} ...}
```

to

```
[{"1009": {...}}, {"1051": {...}}, ...]
```

or (for proper structure)

```
[{"id": "1009", ...}, {"id": "1051", ...}]
```

#### EDIT

Conversion procedure:

```
const json = {"1009": {...}, "1051": {...}}
const arr = Object.keys(json).reduce((temp, key) => {
    temp.push({id: key, ...json[key]})
    return temp;
}, [])
```

Comment: Ok but `ng-repeat` works with objects, it's only `filter` issue

Comment: thnx dorintufar, i found simple solutin, only need to add `toArray:false` thnx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a simple solution, add `toArray:false`

```
ng-repeat="item in items | toArray:false"
```

and now everything working. Thnx to all